# R Studio/R Accessing Blocks of Previously Run Code

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio

Is there a way to display past commands in R/R Studio?? I know in R Studio there is a shortcut (CTRL+UP Arrow) that allows you to see past lines you have ran. But this shortcut only allows you to access only a single line, not a block of previously run code. Is there a package, or some way in R to display and select blocks of past code in R/R Studio?

Comment: The 'history' window is nice.  It's probably on a tab with the 'workspace' window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://wiki.mobilizingcs.org/rstudio/panes) you can find a description of the panes in R Studio, including the "history" pane.
There you can select several lines and paste them into the code.

Also, you can use the command `savehistory()` to save your history in a file you can the modify. If you want to choose the name of the file to be saved, use

`savehistory(file = filename)`

The same option is available in the basic R GUI (MS Windows), with "Save history" in the "File" menu (as a .RHistory file). Then, you can open it with any text editor and modify your history to make a script.

To see a specific number of lines, you can use `history(25)` (for 25 previous lines).

Comment: Bless your heart. Thank you Ricardo. I feel silly I never noticed the history pane on the top right until now.

Comment: @jessica, I added a bit more of info you can use.